# how to handle empty response body in android fast networking library?

Tags: android, retrofit, android-networking

how to handle an empty response body in [android fast networking library](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking)? 
I know in retrofit we have void, but how to handle in fast networking.

POST request, request content type JSON, empty response body with Http code.

retrofit equivalent:

```
@POST("/path/to/get")
Call<Void> getMyData(/* your args here */);
```

my code is below

```
    @Override
    public Single<Response>  checkPhoneNumberAvailabilityApiCall(CheckPhoneNumberAvailabilityRequest checkPhoneNumberAvailabilityRequest) {

         return Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(ApiEndPoint.getEndPoint(ApiEndPoint.ENDPOINTS.CHECK_PHONE_AVAILABLE_API))
                .addHeaders(getHeaders(GENERAL))
                .addJSONObjectBody(convertToJSON(checkPhoneNumberAvailabilityRequest))
                .build()
                .getObjectSingle(Response.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience in Retrofit yet, but hope it helps

```
AndroidNetworking.post(YOUR_ENDPOINT)
                .addHeaders(YOUR_HEADER)
                .addJSONObjectBody(YOUR_JSONOBJECTBODY)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (response.toString().isEmpty()) {
                            //handle empty body
                        } else {
                            //do logic with json value
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        //print log error code
                        Log.e("FAN_ERROR", "ERROR CODE : "+ anError.getErrorCode());
                        //print log error body
                        Log.e("FAN_ERROR", "ERROR BODY : "+ anError.getErrorBody());
                    }
                });
```